# How to add an NSMutableArray to an NSMutableArray Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am making the switch from Java to Objective-c, and I'm having some difficulty. I have searched this problem this without much success.

I have an NSMutableArray that stores NSMutableArrays. How do I add an array to the array?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can either store a reference to another array (or any type of object) in your array:

```
[myArray addObject:otherArray];
```

Or concatenate the arrays.

```
[myArray addObjectsFromArray:otherArray];
```

Both of which are documented in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/index.html).

Comment: myArray.addObjects(from: otherArray as! [Any]) in swift

Answer (score 3):

Since an array is just an object like any other:

```
[myContainerMutableArray addObject:someOtherArray];
```

Or if you want to *concatenate* them:

```
[myFirstMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:otherArray];
```

Answer (score 1):

You add it like any other object.

```
NSMutableArray *innerArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *outerArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[outerArray addObject:innerArray];
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if you add the same NSMutableArray Object, Like

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"test1",@"test2",@"test3",nil];

NSMutableArray *mutableArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"test4",@"test5",@"test6", nil];

mutableArray1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray1];

[mutableArray1 addObjectsFromArray:mutableArray2]; 

Nslog(@"mutableArray1 : %@",mutableArray1);
```

Comment: yes, It will...  OUTPUT: mutableArray1 : (
    test1,
    test2,
    test3,
    test4,
    test5,
    test6
)

Answer (score 0):

[YourArray addObjectsFromArray:OtherArray];